adb pull silently disconnects device if the filename is correct
From the command line on ubuntu,
adb pull /sdcard/magisk_patched.img .

fails with exit code 1.
Subsequent pulls fail with adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found
Unplugging and replugging the USB cable is the only way I've found to find the device again, killing and restarting the adb server doesn't work.
If I give it a filename that doesn't exist, it fails with adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/sdcard/magisk_patcd.img': No such file or directory
And does not disconnect.
So it's FINDING the file, but fails to transport it back to the PC so badly that the connection is perma-borked? It was able to push a file to that directory, does it not have permission to READ that file? If so, why isn't it giving an error to that effect?
I'm using ubuntu, and successfully used adb to push the file earlier. Using a local disk. No spaces in the filenames (I showed the actual commands with the actual file names) and the pathnames are short too.
The phone IS encrypted. According to adb pull not finding a file that's clearly there
that will cause it to "not find the file" with no other details. However, it IS finding the file? If this is an encryption related issue, how do I bypass it? Uploading it via chrome to my website may work? tries it configuring POST on a webserver is hard. Still working on it.
Is there a better way? Is it the encryption? There's no error message, so it's hard to tell why it's failing.

It doesn't matter if the device is encrypted or not if the device is booted into regular OS and if it protected by a lock screen you have at least once entered the correct lock screen PIN/password. Use adb shell and the regular linux commands to see what files exist if pulling fails.
